# Does size of caffemodel proportional to number of parameter?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

the *.cafemodel is an output of a network after the training phase. Do you think its size is proportional to the number of parameters? It means that if I have two networks A and B, the network A results in *.caffemodel with size 10MB in the disk, while network B results in a *.caffemodel with size 20MB in the disk. Is it right if I said the network A has less number of learnable parameter than network B?

Comment: I don't think that can be certainly said. First model might have weight with float values and 2nd one with double.

Comment: it must be the same type to fair comparison

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.  The size is mostly dependent on the memory needed to store the parameters *and* weights.  This includes not only the quantity of each, but the data size as well.  If one model is set up to work with short fixed-point arithmetic, while another uses normal floats, there will be a large discrepancy in storage needs.

Also, layer connectivity has a lot to do with the file size.  A fully-connected layer has far more weights than a convolution layer involving the same quantities of parameters.

Does that help sort things out a little?

Comment: .@Prune - That means the size of `.caffemodel` is always constant irrespective of the iteration and batch size for the given network? I observe that for `AlexNet` having any number of iteration or batch size, the model file is around `230MB` for all.

Comment: Right -- for a given topology, each of the checkpoints should be the same size, with minor variations for labeling information.